# Difference in font styling in two different HTML components

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am not sure why font is getting messed up in two different components of my website. Check difference in font of the content inside VirtualStockMarket vs content inside Rules and Note.

[image]

```html
<div class="container rules">
  <br>
  <h3>
    VirtualStockMarket
  </h3>
  <hr>
  <p> Event that allows you to buy stocks using virtual money. The principal objective is to achieve maximum capital appreciation over a period of 4 weeks starting 25th Sep, 2019 through 25th Oct, 2019.
  </p>
  <br>
  <h3>Rules</h3>
  <hr>
  <ol>
    <li> Maximum Investment: INR 1 cr. </li>
    <li> Stock Universe: Constituents of Nifty 200 Index – the eligible stocks will be prepopulated on the Buy Screen </li>
    <li> Portfolio Re-Balancing: Every Monday. Participants can rebalance their portfolio allocations every week any time after 3.30 PM on Friday (or the last day of week) through to 8.59 AM on Monday (or first day of the week)
    </li>
    <li> No limit on the number of stocks one can buy</li>
    <li> Any unallocated amount will automatically be reflected as Cash </li>
  </ol>

  <br>
  <h3>Note</h3>
  <hr>
  <ol>
    <li>Stock prices are not updated in real time.</li>
    <li>Leaderboard is updated every hour.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share an example of where this occurs? I don't see it when I run your HTML code in JSFiddle.

Comment: If you right click on the problematic text in your browser and select "inspect", you can see all the css applied to it. You will probably find some css that is applied to the <p> tag and not to the <li> tag or vice versa.